# What is the usage of a class?

Tags: vb.net, oop

I understand how to create a class. I understand how to work with it in normal situations. However, I don't see the point of the reason. Can someone give clarification?

Comment: I don't mean to be insulting here, but frankly this question is not one that should really appear on SO.  This is not the place to come to learn theoretical concepts, a good book on OO will be a much better place to start

Comment: Have you heard of google? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx)

Comment: See [What is better in calling a method: creating an object, or make the method static?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24997534/3453226).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the point is to make coding more manageable. easier to add and ASSOCIATE functions, properties attributes etc than individually coding them as separate entities.

For instance you write functions to change system sound, one to increase it, other to decrease it and third to mute it. In non-OO languages they would literally be like Increasesoundfunc, Decreasesoundfunc and mutesoundfunc. while in OO they'd be like Soundclass.inreasesound, Soundclass.decreasesound ,Soundclass.mutesound . Horrible example, but you get the point.

Comment: Mark, thank you for taking the time to understand my question and give a clear response. I am new to OOP. However, i now see the benefit of using class's.

Answer (score 1):

Return to the Basics... A Class supposed to be a representation of an object from the real live, most of the time this is true, maybe its only how the computer its able to understand us.
  Something its true about the classes: everything, every system, dll, framework, control, etc, etc, was made from a lot of classes.

hope it help you.... :)